# Is mapM in Haskell strict? Why does this program get a stack overflow?

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

The following program terminates correctly:

```
import System.Random

randomList = mapM (\_->getStdRandom (randomR (0, 50000::Int))) [0..5000]

main = do
  randomInts <- randomList
  print $ take 5 randomInts
```

Running:

```
$ runhaskell test.hs
[26156,7258,29057,40002,26339]
```

However, feeding it with an infinite list, the program never terminates, and when compiled, eventually gives a stack overflow error!

```
import System.Random

randomList = mapM (\_->getStdRandom (randomR (0, 50000::Int))) [0..]

main = do
  randomInts <- randomList
  print $ take 5 randomInts
```

Running,

```
$ ./test
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

I expected the program to lazily evaluate `getStdRandom` each time I pick an item off the list, finishing after doing so 5 times.  Why is it trying to evaluate the whole list?

Thanks.

Is there a better way to get an infinite list of random numbers?  I want to pass this list into a pure function.

EDIT: Some more reading revealed that the function

```
randomList r = do g <- getStdGen
                  return $ randomRs r g
```

is what I was looking for.

EDIT2: after reading camccann's answer, I realized that `getStdGen` is getting a new seed on every call.  Instead, better to use this function as a simple one-shot random list generator:

```
import System.Random

randomList :: Random a => a -> a -> IO [a]
randomList r g = do s <- newStdGen
                    return $ randomRs (r,g) s

main = do r <- randomList 0 (50::Int)
          print $ take 5 r
```

But I still don't understand why my `mapM` call did not terminate.  Evidently not related to random numbers, but something to do with `mapM` maybe.

For example, I found that the following also does not terminate:

```
randomList = mapM (\_->return 0) [0..]

main = do
  randomInts <- randomList
  print $ take 50000 randomInts
```

What gives?  By the way, IMHO, the above `randomInts` function should be in `System.Random`.  It's extremely convenient to be able to very *simply* generate a random list in the IO monad and pass it into a pure function when needed, I don't see why this should not be in the standard library.

Comment: Oh, and as an addendum to my answer: You can write a more general version of `randomInts` as just `\r -> fmap (randomRs r) getStdGen`. This has type `(Random a) => (a, a) -> IO [a]`, in other words, it generates a list of random values in the given range for any type that's an instance of `Random`.

Comment: I guess that's why my `randomList` function wouldn't even need to be in the standard lib if it can be that short, but boy is it not obvious how to write that for a newb ;)  So I still think it should be there for convenience sake..

Comment: I agree that `randomList` should be standard in `System.Random`.  Even if it's short, it's incredibly common, highly useful, and particularly idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Haskell's mapM not lazy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270255/is-haskells-mapm-not-lazy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do something more like this, letting randomRs do the work with an initial RandomGen:

```
#! /usr/bin/env runhaskell

import Control.Monad
import System.Random


randomList :: RandomGen g => g -> [Int]
randomList = randomRs (0, 50000)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   randomInts <- liftM randomList newStdGen
   print $ take 5 randomInts
```

As for the laziness, what's happening here is that `mapM` is `(sequence . map)`

Its type is: `mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`

It's mapping the function, giving a `[m b]` and then needs to execute all those actions to make an `m [b]`. It's the sequence that'll never get through the infinite list.

This is explained better in the answers to a prior question: [Is Haskell's mapM not lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270255/is-haskells-mapm-not-lazy)

Answer (score 12):

Random numbers in general are not strict, but *monadic binding* is--the problem here is that `mapM` has to sequence the entire list. Consider its type signature, `(a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`; as this implies, what it does is first `map` the list of type `[a]` into a list of type `[m b]`, then `sequence` that list to get a result of type `m [b]`. So, when you bind the result of applying `mapM`, *e.g.* by putting it on the right-hand side of `<-`, what this means is "map this function over the list, then execute each monadic action, and combine the results back into a single list". If the list is infinite, this of course won't terminate.

If you simply want a stream of random numbers, you need to generate the list without using a monad for each number. I'm not entirely sure why you've used the design you have, but the basic idea is this: Given a seed value, use a pseudo-random number generator to produce a pair of 1) a random number 2) a new seed, then repeat with the new seed. Any given seed will of course provide the same sequence each time. So, you can use the function `getStdGen`, which will provide a fresh seed in the `IO` monad; you can then use that seed to create an infinite sequence in completely pure code.

In fact, `System.Random` provides functions for precisely that purpose, `randoms` or `randomRs` instead of `random` and `randomR`.

If for some reason you want to do it yourself, what you want is essentially an *unfold*. The function `unfoldr` from `Data.List` has the type signature `(b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]`, which is fairly self-explanatory: Given a value of type `b`, it applies the function to get either something of type `a` and  a new generator value of type `b`, or `Nothing` to indicate the end of the sequence.

You want an infinite list, so will never need to return `Nothing`. Thus, partially applying `randomR` to the desired range and composing it with `Just` gives this:

```
Just . randomR (0, 50000::Int) :: (RandomGen a) => a -> Maybe (Int, a)
```

Feeding that into `unfoldr` gives this:

```
unfoldr (Just . randomR (0, 50000::Int)) :: (RandomGen a) => a -> [Int]
```

...which does exactly as it claims: Given an instance of `RandomGen`, it will produce an infinite (and *lazy*) list of random numbers generated from that seed.

Comment: unfoldr! Why do I never use unfolds? They're great.