# Why does this haskell code not terminate

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, state-monad

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

type Queue a = [a]

push :: a -> State (Queue a) ()
push x = state (\xs -> ((),xs++[x]))

pop :: State (Queue a) a
pop = state (\(x:xs) -> (x,xs))

queueManip :: State (Queue Int) Int
queueManip =
  do
    mapM_ push [1..]
    a <- pop
    return a

main :: IO()
main = do
  let (a,_) = runState queueManip []
  print a
```

Shouldn't the `mapM_` be lazy ? Besides for implementing a queue shouldn't the complexity be `O(1)`?

Because the append `(++)` itself is lazy ...

Comment: Though not exactly the same, have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270255/is-haskells-mapm-not-lazy ?

Answer (score 5):

What if I'm evil and use

```
push' :: Int -> State (Queue Int) ()
push' 1052602983 = state $ \_ -> ((), []) -- "Muarhar!"
push' x = state $ \xs -> ((),xs++[x])
```

Then `mapM push' [1..]` should clearly render the state as `[1052602983, 1052602984 ..]`. It would be wrong for `pop` to yield `1`. But `mapM` can't possibly know this, without first evaluating a billion other numbers. Actually pushing them to the state is irrelevant here, and it also doesn't matter that `push` could be completely lazy: `mapM` at least has to give it a *chance* to check any given number, before handing on the monadic program flow.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `do mapM_ push [1..3]; something` is the same as:

```
do push 1; push 2; push 3; something
```

so that should explain why

```
do mapM_ push [1..]; something
```

never gets around to executing `something`.

If you look at the definition of the State monad:

```
type State s a = s -> (a, s)

instance Monad (State s) where
  return a = \s -> (a,s)
  m >>= g = wpAB
    where
      wpAB = \s1 -> let (v2, s2) = m s1
                        (v3, s3) = g v2 s2
                    in (v3, s3)

-- (newtypes and such have been removed to declutter the code)
```

you see that the value of `m >>= g` always depends on `g`. Contrast that with the definition of `Maybe` monad:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    return x = Just x
    (>>=) m g = case m of
                  Nothing -> Nothing
                  Just x  -> g x
```

where `m >>= g` can be independent of `g` which explains how the `Maybe` monad can short-circuit a do-chain.

Comment: I think this could be a valid argument, but you still need to show that an infinite `do` chain can't just be skipped lazily, like many other things in Haskell.

Comment: Yes - there are monads where an do infinite chain does not have to be completely evaluated - e.g. the Maybe monad.

Comment: so, why is the argument valid for `State` then?

Comment: Okay this being said, is there any way that a queue could be implemented via some other monad? Could the desired laziness be enforced via some other monad?

Comment: Just remove the `mapM_ push [1..]` from `queueManip` and run your computation with `runState queueManip [1..]`.