# How to generate an infinite list of random numbers using randomRIO?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to generate an infinite list of random numbers using randomRIO.

```
import System.Random

g :: IO [Integer]
g = do
  n <- randomRIO (1,6) :: IO Integer
  f <- g
  return (n : f)
```

It compiles but hangs when run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it never teminates. Whenever you execute `g`, it initially calcuates the first random number and stores it in `n`. Then it again recursively calls back to the same function `g` which goes on and on. To get an infinite list you can use the `randomRs` function:

```
g2 :: IO [Integer]
g2 = do
  g <- newStdGen
  return $ randomRs (1,6) g
```

And then you can produce any number of random numbers using it:

```
λ> g2 >>= \x -> return $ take 5 $ x
[5,4,6,5,6]
```

Comment: This won't work correctly: `getStdGen` does not update the global RNG state, like `randomRIO` does. You need `getStdRandom` to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can't, for much the same [reason why you can't lazily `mapM` over `State`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270255/is-haskells-mapm-not-lazy) (and then use the result state afterwards). `randomRIO` produces a single value and only hands on the monadic program flow after this value has been produced.

The way to produce infinite streams of random values is of course `randomRs`. You can easily couple it with [`getStdRandom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#globalrng) to produce such streams right in `IO`:

```
import Control.Arrow

randomRsIO :: Random a => (a,a) -> IO [a]
randomRsIO range = getStdRandom $ split >>> first (randomRs range)
```

With that,

```
g :: IO [Integer]
g = randomRsIO (1,6)
```

Comment: You can do it with [`unsafeInterleaveIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeInterleaveIO): `g = do {r <- randomRIO (1,6); rs <- unsafeInterleaveIO g; return (r:rs)}`. But unless I had a reason, I'd use your approach.

Comment: I generally pretend the `unsafeXyzIO` functions don't exist. (But you're right, this could actually be a safe use case... but I don't see any benefit over `randomRs`.)

Comment: I can't compile `randomRsIO`. `Couldn't match type ‘[a]’ with ‘([a], StdGen)’`

Comment: Right, that's because `randomRs` doesn't return an updated generator. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `Arrow` :)

Comment: I think you mean `IO`, not `State` - some kinds of lazy `mapM` work just fine in `State`, e.g. the `mapM return [1..]` in your link. (Just don't try to get at the "afterward" state.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen well, e.g. `mapM return [1..] >> state (const((),()))` terminates, it's true. But that's basically just a way of decoupling a “thread” of state. That thread will never terminate.

Comment: Because of laziness, "never terminate" doesn't mean it cannot be useful. Another example that actually *uses* the state: `evalState (mapM (\x -> modify (+x) >> get) $ [1..]) 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted an answer using randomRIO. I know its been a long time since the question was asked.

This is using liftM where you can generate a random number in range low `l` to high `h` and keep appending to a list num times. So we have a list of length `num` of random numbers.

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Random
gx :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
gx l h num = do
        x <- randomRIO(l,h)
        if num <=1 then return [x] else liftM (x:) (gx l h (num-1))
```